# How can I create gamma rays with energy >2MeV?

Tags: experimental-physics, nuclear-physics, experimental-technique, gamma-rays, experimental-technology

I have been exploring pair production (electron/positron) using gamma, and with a Cobalt-60 source this is easy enough. That's just the problem, though.

I'm looking for a challenge. I want a stream of gamma photons that is at least above 2 MeV. Radioactive sources are weak and unpredictable, and pair production is just too hard to observe feasibly. My question is, how can I create an assembly to give photons higher energies? What are my options? I'm rather new to this, and this is the first genuine project that I'm ready to undertake. Other than that, I've only made a small AmBe neutron emitter.

Comment: Radiation oncology treatments often are done with X-ray sources with energies in the low tens of MeV. The source is a tungsten target that is bombarded with electrons from a small electron linear accelerator. For example: https://www.varian.com/oncology/products/treatment-delivery

Comment: If your experiment is portable, you might get lucky and find an under-utilized treatment center that would be willing to rent you some time on their machine.

Comment: What does the "luminosity" of this stream have to be (photons/s), and how "clean" does it have to be (in terms of energy spread around 2 MeV)? The answers to these questions restrict the possible designs greatly (for example, electron synchrotron radiation might give you great luminosity, but a very broad energy spectrum). Also, this question might be closed for being an engineering question.

Comment: @SolomonSlow That is also how medical dental x-ray machines work, though they may be optimized for a lower energy band. Of course a Thorium-232 source provides the highest energy gamma line (from the Talium-208 daughter).

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the range of luminosity that would be realistic for an amateur assembly, but I do know I need enough photons entering the cloud chamber to interact with nuclei and produce pairs. As for cleanliness, I only need the beam to reach above 2 MeV. Past that point, I would prefer the beam to remain below 10 MeV if possible. I could certainly say luminosity is less important when compared to cleanliness. I just need some suggestions, I suppose.

Comment: @Slowmover35, I don't know what "cleanliness" means, but the energy spectrum from medical X-ray sources is broad, the apparent source diameter is some single-digit number of millimeters, and the machine may or may not pass the beam through an aluminium "flattening filter" that is intended to give approximately constant intensity across the width of the beam. The oldest machines hit the target with electrons having as little as 4 or 6 MeV. I dropped out of that industry at least a decade ago. The newest machines at that time offered a selection of two or three different beam energies.

Comment: I hope you are using appropriate shielding for your experiments.

Comment: Build a little synchrotron with relativistic electrons and a suitable laser. Then use those for doing inverse Compton scattering.

Comment: this might interest you , though not within the reach of a simple experiment https://indico.cern.ch/event/718723/contributions/3194963/attachments/1777619/2890572/Epiphany2019_WP.pdf

Comment: also this https://phys.org/news/2019-06-method-intense-x-ray-gamma-ray.html . but you will need a few more MeV electrons than the gamma energy you want